# Styling amazon affliate links

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe, amazon-product-api

I have a page where multiple amazon affiliate links will be displayed on the page like so.

```
{amazon.map((amazon) => (
          <div className="col-sm-4" key={amazon.link}>
             <iframe
              style={{height: '300px', width: '300px'}}
              marginwidth="0"
              marginheight="0"
              scrolling="no"
              frameborder="0"
              src={amazon.link}
            ></iframe>
          </div>
        ))}
```

This is working fine, (the links are stored in a json file). However when I try to make the thumbnails of the images larger, the images stays the same size and the width/height between the affiliate items grows larger.
[image: like so]

How am I able to style the products?
Thank you in advance.

Just in case it's needed:

> [github repo](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/Puppywebsite)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to edit what's inside of the iframe since an iframe is rendering amazon's web page which you do not have control over. A way to work around this would be to manually create the product card yourself instead of using amazon's provided iframe. Amazon affiliate provides a plain URL link you could use to build your own card.

Comment: It looks like that's what I'll be doing, thank you.